# What I can used to detect shape similar to circles in python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

[image]

This is the image and my aim is to detect only the middle nuclei of cell

Code for detecting nuclei shape (similar to circle) from below image

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
planets = cv2.imread('52.BMP')
gray_img    =   cv2.cvtColor(planets,   cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = cv2.medianBlur(gray_img,  5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,120,param1=100,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
circles=circles.astype(float)
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
                cv2.circle(planets,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),6)
                cv2.circle(planets,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
cv2.imshow("HoughCirlces",  planets)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm getting this error everytime

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rint'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\ABHISHEK\PycharmProjects\cervical_project1\hsv.py", line 33, in <module>
        circles = np.uint64(np.around(circles))
      File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in around
      File "C:\python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 3348, in around
        return _wrapfunc(a, 'round', decimals=decimals, out=out)
      File "C:\python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 54, in _wrapfunc
        return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
      File "C:\python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 43, in _wrapit
        result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
    TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type NoneType which has no callable rint method
```

Is there any other way to detect only the nuclei of cell?

Comment: why does the error talk about `"rint"` and why do I not see that in your code? please review [mre]

Comment: note: hough transform for ovals is expensive. and it still won't work well for "lumpy circles", like you have in biology. -- instead, find contours, then filter by a measure of circularity, that allows you to be tolerant of real shapes that aren't platonic ideas.

Comment: there is no 'rint' I have written in my code it is the type of error I m asking it is not written by me

Comment: please review [mre]. this is crucial. we need _the_ code and _the_ error that _this_ code causes.

Comment: As the name indicates, HoughCircles detects circles, not potato shapes. In addition, the edges are pretty blurry, which is a second reason to make it fail.

Answer (score 1):

For large images hough transformation based searches can become slow.
Since you have a contrast difference between cell and nucleus you could transform your image into a grayscale image (maybe even using only one color channel if the contrast is better in a single one) and then applying blob detection. That also allows for filtering the nuclei according to certain shapes or sizes.

Edit:
Your submitted traceback says that the error comes from line 33 of hsv.py. As Christoph Rackwitz already stated, the provided code is missing this part or the error message doesn't correspond to your code.
Anyway in your line

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,120,param1=100,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
```

you are setting minRadius and maxRadius to 0. Probably because of this no circle is found and np.around tries to act on None which leads to your final error message.

Comment: This is the only code I have written in hsv.py I m not getting this error that's why I have posted it in stackoverflow there is not even in single line I have written "rint"

Comment: Can you help me with it??

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. I just copied your code, only replaced the image and it ran just fine. The error message states that the line 'circles = np.uint64(np.around(circles))' generates the error. Most likely None is passed to np.around so probably no circle was found. Rint is a method used by numpy for the rounding. Are you sure you were running this exact script that produced the error message? Because the error message mentions hsv.py and np.uint64 which is not used in the provided code.

Answer (score 1):

Binarization of the green component gives a usable result. Use contouring, and filter out the unwanted blobs. (You could rely on the isoperimetric ratio.)

[image]

Unfortunately, this method will be very sensitive to the color mixture.

Comment: @VC.One: such considerations are application-dependent, so it is premature to tell.

Comment: Would Gaussian blurring not help to "circularize" that centre blob/potato? After a "where to look" position is known via Gaussian/blur space with some `HoughCircles` involvement, it can later be applied to the binarized version where Asker can then "fine tune" the exact shape detection (_eg:_ in that area, ignore white pixels and keep only black pixels).

Comment: Using Hough on a non-circular, poorly contrasted image is a nonsense when you have a nice isolated blob by binarization. Forget Hough.

Comment: OK I get your point. Basically `HoughCircles` should not even enter the equation here.